# Rabbitmq connection reset is causing the message to be dispatched twice

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have a batch job where the job is divided into multiple small messages and pushed to queue and multiple workers listening to queue would pick up and process these messages.

When connection reset happened as shown below the same message was picked up by another worker instance even when the 1st worker has picked it before and is still processing.

```
ERROR org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$DefaultChannelCloseLogger:Channel shutdown: connection error
com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler:An unexpected connection driver error occured (Exception message: Connection reset)
```

This happened only with one message of a particular job and the connection reset time matches with that particular message redispatch.

I would want to know if this is a valid functionality as part of rabbitmq autoRecovery and unavoidable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct; any unacknowledged message will be requeued and redelivered after a connection reset.

Comment: Thank you for the response Gary. Any suggestions on handling this scenario ? Is there something I can do at the rabbit mq config level while setting up the connection to avoid this as this is happening somewhat frequently. Or do I have to check if the message received is a duplicate one in my application code ?

Comment: There is nothing that can be done (except fixing the network to stop the connection problems). RabbitMQ provides at least once delivery guarantees; you need to deal with duplicates. Or, you can acknowledge the message before processing - but that risks message loss if your application crashes, unless you secure the request somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry for asking here. Can you please help with this Gary
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70108476/spring-amqp-is-it-possible-to-hook-a-custom-handler-before-a-basicget