# Spring Amqp - Is it possible to hook a custom handler before a basicGet()?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have a message handler which is annotated with `@RabbitHandler` which picks up and process messages from the queue.

**Use case**

During deployment times, the instance should not be picking any messages from the queue. Is there some place where I can hook and check if my instance is blocked (read from db to check) and stop receiving messages. I checked that we have `setAfterReceivePostProcessors` but what I am actually looking for is something like `beforeReceiveProcessor` to solve my use case of checking and not polling at all. It should not be reaching my `@RabbitHandler` method at all. Is it possible to achieve this level of control ?

If not, is the only possible way is to write a custom poller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The infrastructure behind `@RabbitListener` uses `basicConsume()`, not `basicGet()`.

You can control the lifecycle of the listener container using the `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` bean.

```
@RabbitListener(id = "foo", ..., autoStartup = "false")
```

Then

```
registry.getListenerContainer("foo").start();
```

You can use a property placeholder too.

```
@RabbitListener(id = "foo", ..., autoStartup = "${should.start:false}")
```